# Convert datetime64[ns] Index to date pandas for comparison

Tags: pandas, datetime, datetime-format, python-datetime

I have the following python code:

```
current_ts = datetime.datetime.now()
current_date = current_ts.date()

new_df = df[df.index >= current_date]
```

The `df.index` is a datetime64[ns] and when I run the code I get `Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date`.

How can I convert the index into a date so that the comparison works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pandas `datetime64[ns]` doesn't compare directly to `datetime.date`. You need to convert:

```
df[df.index >= pd.Timestamp(current_date)]
```